# What creates "libloc_%2f...Builts.rds" temporary files in R?

Tags: r, temporary-files

I'm running a server process in R that is restarted often, and which uses many R packages. Right now, each restart creates a temporary directory that contains a couple of files with the "rds" extension. I'd really like to know which R package or feature causes these .rds files to be created (so I can disable that). Thanks!

The filenames look like this:

libloc_%2fusr%2flib%2fR%2flibraryVersion,Priority,Depends,Imports,LinkingTo,Suggests,Enhances,OS_type,License,Archs,Built.rds

and the beginning of the content look like this:

```
      [,1]         [,2]                 [,3]          [,4]          [,5]                                              
 [1,] "KernSmooth" "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.23-6"      "recommended" "R (>= 2.5.0), stats"                             
 [2,] "MASS"       "/usr/lib/R/library" "7.3-13"      "recommended" "R (>= 2.13.0), grDevices, graphics, stats, utils"
 [3,] "Matrix"     "/usr/lib/R/library" "0.999375-50" "recommended" "R (>= 2.10.0), stats, methods, utils, lattice"   
 [4,] "base"       "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        NA                                                
 [5,] "class"      "/usr/lib/R/library" "7.3-2"       "recommended" "R (>= 2.5.0), stats, utils"                      
 [6,] "compiler"   "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        NA                                                
 [7,] "datasets"   "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        NA                                                
 [8,] "grDevices"  "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        NA                                                
 [9,] "graphics"   "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        NA                                                
[10,] "grid"       "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        NA                                                
[11,] "lattice"    "/usr/lib/R/library" "0.19-26"     "recommended" "R (>= 2.11.0)"                                   
[12,] "methods"    "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        NA                                                
[13,] "nnet"       "/usr/lib/R/library" "7.3-1"       "recommended" "R (>= 2.5.0), stats, utils"                      
[14,] "spatial"    "/usr/lib/R/library" "7.3-2"       "recommended" "R (>= 2.5.0), graphics, stats, utils"            
[15,] "splines"    "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        NA                                                
[16,] "stats"      "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        NA                                                
[17,] "stats4"     "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        "methods, graphics, stats"                        
[18,] "tcltk"      "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        NA                                                
[19,] "tools"      "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        NA                                                
[20,] "utils"      "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.13.0"      "base"        NA
```

Comment: Since `saveRDS` is a base R function, you'll have to provide **much** more information in your question if you want an answer.

Comment: I didn't know about `saveRDS` and `readRDS`. Thanks. Added more details.

Comment: Perhaps you want to tell us which server process you are running?

Comment: It's a custom-written forecasting model server. Not all that relevant to the question, in my mind. (I have similar behavior when running the R code without the server.) Basically, my problem is that I'm using a whole lot of R packages, and one of them is creating these `.rds` files under the hood. I'm hoping someone can look at the files, recognize them and say "Oh yeah, that's created when you use the X function of package Y."

Comment: Is that exactly the filename you are getting?  And the content is that table stored in plain text?

Comment: Yes, that's the exact filename (with the "2f"'s). And the contents pasted above is the result of `print(readRDS(that_filename.rds))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like file created by `installed.packages()`. Check source of this function.

Maybe you have call to it in startup profile (e.g. `update.packages()` on session start)?

You could enable tracing of `saveRDS` function, e.g. add to .Rprofile:

```
trace("saveRDS", function() print(str(head(sys.calls(),-5))))
```

This will print (you could dump it into file also) call stack, e.g. when I run `update.packages(ask='graphics')` then on console I got:

```
Tracing saveRDS(res0, dest, compress = TRUE) on entry 
List of 3
 $ : language update.packages(ask = "graphics")
 $ : language available.packages(contriburl = contriburl, method = method)
 $ : language saveRDS(res0, dest, compress = TRUE)
NULL
Tracing saveRDS(res0, dest, compress = TRUE) on entry 
List of 3
 $ : language update.packages(ask = "graphics")
 $ : language available.packages(contriburl = contriburl, method = method)
 $ : language saveRDS(res0, dest, compress = TRUE)
# ..... and few more calls ...............
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Running `installed.packages()` on another computer produces the same three files. And the culprit in this case is `glmnet`, which calls `installed.packages()` to print its version number. Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: @ChristianHudon New version of glmnet package (1.7.1, released 2011-09-23) don't use `installed.packages()`.